# Git Workflow for Feature Branch

Tags: git, branch

I've created a feature branch several weeks ago, did some changes, but haven't done anything for like 2 weeks. Now the master branch obviously changed during that time.

What is the best workflow to follow here? Do I rebase the feature branch with the master so I get the most recent update in my feature branch or do I keep on working on the feature branch and then only update when I'm done, and then start to merge possible conflicts?

Comment: Is a fast-forward merge possible?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use `rebase`, if you mean that with fast-forward merge?

Comment: Sorry, a better question is 'Have you confirmed you actually have merge conflicts'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should merge/rebase ASAP. If you wait then more differences will appear and it will be harder to fix all the conflicts.

Usually you should merge/rebase every day, that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the two branches separate. simply switch to the feature branch and do a pull from master.

```
git checkout feature_branch
git pull origin master
```

or

```
git checkout feature_branch
git pull master
```

whichever is more up to date.  then fix the conflicts in your feature branch, and merge it with master using a --no-ff.  this will keep a the history of the two branches separate.

I'd suggest taking a look at the work flow defined here:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/